# how to sort embedded array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple schema of blog with embedded comments, which is modeled in mongoose

```
var BlogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          ...............,
         comments:[Comment],
         visits:int  
});

var Comment = mongoose.Schema({
    name  :  { type: String }
  , img   :  { type:String }
  , date  :  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  , text  :  String 
});

var BlogModel = mongoose.model('Blog',BlogSchema);

function findCommentsById(id,option,callback){

    var id;
    try {
         id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
    } catch(e) {
        return callback(e, null);
    }

    BlogModel.findById(id,{'comments':{ $slice: [ option.skip ,option.limit] }},{'sort':{'comments.date':1}},function(err, comm) { 
        if(err){callback(err, null);}
        else{
            console.log("findCourseCommentsById".red,comm);
            callback(null, comm);
        }      
    })

}
```

The first issue is when I return the first two entry of embedded array, using slice is ok that the first two comments are retrieved, but how to sort out the comments by date, {'sort':{'comments.date':1}} doesn't seem to work. Also it returns me a full documents, but in fact what I really need is to return me comments only

```
function addComment(bid,name,img,text,callback){

    var options = { new: false, select: 'comments' };         
    BlogModel.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':bid},{'$push':{'comments':{'name':name,'img':img,'text':text}},'$inc':{'visits':1}},options,function(err,ref){
        if(err) {
            console.log('add addComment'.red,err);
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
            console.log('add addComment  '.green+ref);                
            callback(null,ref);
        }
    })  
}
```

Another question relates to the use of findOneAndUpdate, when the documents get updated, the callback will return me a document, which in some cases returning a response with a full document is costly, what I want is when I update, it doesn't give me a response. I have seen the mongodb, which says it is possible, but when it comes to mongoose, I haven't seen anything talking about don't return a document when updating.

So I went back to mongoose doc on [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, [update], [options], [callback]), the [options] has a select field allowing me to return selected fields/ partial document. option = {  select: '_id '}, this works ok, but if I want to return nothing for the sake of optimization, leaving select blank, for example option = {  select: ''}, this doesn't work and will return me a full doc.

Comment: sort applies to documents being returned, not fields or array elements within the document.

Comment: Right, it makes sense. so I guess when the mongodb returns the array, I can just reverse the array in javascript

Comment: that's one possibility, another would be to use the aggregation framework to have it done on the server - you need to $unwind the comments array, then sort, match the ones you want and then you can group them back to get back a single document (if that's important).

Comment: On the second part of your question, use `update` instead of `findOneAndUpdate` if you don't want the doc returned.

Comment: Thank you, Johnny. I didn't realize the true use of update before, thanks a lot

Comment: I would suggest that you sort your array when inserting elements in it. You could use the mentioned technique : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/